# Variadic template type unpacking into map keys

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a class which will contain a map of `type_index` keys mapped to pointers of each type passed as a template argument. This would allow me to specify a series of types my class will rely on in it's declaration.

I've done a bit of research but can only seem to find ways to unpack arguments, rather than types. I'm new to this subject, and would appreciate any clarification on terminology, or references to relevant text.

```
template <typename T>
T* SomeFakeFactoryGetter() { return new T(); }

template <class... Injected>
class UtilityProvider
{
public:
    template <class U>
    U* GetUtility()
    {
        std::type_index idx = std::type_index(typeid(U));
        assert(_injectedClasses.find(idx) != _injectedClasses.end());
        return reinterpret_cast<U*>(_injectedClasses[idx]);
    }

    // **
    // How would I *unpack* all types for use as indices into my map?
    // ( I realise this function is not what I want.)
    template <Injected... C>
    void Unpack()
    {
        _injectedClasses[std::type_index(typeid(C))] = SomeFakeFactoryGetter<C>();
    }

private:
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::type_index, void*> InjectedMap;
    InjectedMap _injectedClasses;
};

class Bar{ public: void A() { printf("Hello bar"); } };
class Baz{ public: void B() { printf("Hello baz"); } };
class Nope {};

class Foo : public UtilityProvider<Bar, Baz>
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        GetUtility<Bar>()->A();
        GetUtility<Nope>(); // Fail. User must specify which utilities this class     will use.
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in this situation is to create a dummy function to expand these expressions into, but it looks quite hideous:

```
    template <int ... Dummies>
    void dummy(int&& ...){}

    template <class ... C>
    void Unpack()
    {
       dummy(((_injectedClasses[std::type_index(typeid(C))] = 
                 SomeFakeFactoryGetter<C>()), 0)...);
    }
```

Note that in your case I think you'll be better off with using `insert` with an `initializer_list`:

```
    template <class ... C>
    void Unpack()
    {
      _injectedClasses.insert({std::make_pair(std::type_index(typeid(C)),
                                              SomeFakeFactoryGetter<C>())...});
    }
```

I couldn't find a direct mention of this but I believe there is an important difference between the two methods, in case you didn't already know.  `insert` will not override existing key-value pairs, whereas `operator[]` will.  This can affect which method you should use if if this is important to you.

Comment: That works awesome - thanks for the heads up on the initializer lists solution.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
template <typename ... C> struct Unpacker;

template <typename Tail, typename ... Queue>
struct Unpacker<Tail, Queue...>
{
    void operator () (InjectedMap& injectedClasses) const
    {
        _injectedClasses[std::type_index(typeid(Tail))] = SomeFakeFactoryGetter<Tail>();
        Unpacker<Queue...>()(injectedClasses);
    }
};

template <>
struct Unpacker<>
{
    void operator () (InjectedMap& injectedClasses) const {}
};
```